# What does "popping bottle" symbolise?

Tags: meaning, verbs, nouns

I keep hearing the phrase "popping bottle" in contemporary music. Does it simply mean "opening an alcoholic drink"? Why do they keep using it?

- > I invented swag, poppin bottles, putting supermodels in the cab.
  >   *Otis* — Kanye West
- > popping bottles in the club
  >   *Love In This Club* — Usher
- > popping bottles in the club
  >   *Lollipop* — Lil' Wayne ft. Static
- *Poppin Bottles* — T.I. feat. Drake
- > Popping bottles with model
  >   *Troublemaker* — Akon
- > Popping bottles in LA
  >   *Best Night* — LMFAO
- > Popping bottles up for free
  >   *Reminds Me* — LMFAO
- > Popping bottle in the house with model in the V-I-P
  >   *Sorry for party rocking* — LMFAO
- > Popping these bottles, touching these model 
  >   *Right Round* — Flo Rida
- > Popping bottles in the ice
  >   *Like a G6* — Far East Movement

Why this choice of words? Does this phrase symbolise something?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=popping%20bottles

Comment: @Kris. I posted my answer before seeing your comment. Honest.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Mine was just a comment in any case. :)

Comment: Uh. If you are not even sure what the phrase *means*, how can you say the people using it "keep misusing it" and something is "wrong with them"? −1 for peeving bordering on insults.

Comment: @RegDwighт I was only wondering why they use it so frequently. I didn't say they've misused it. And I didn't mean to insult.

Comment: @Barrie all comments and answers have exact timestamps. Just hover over the time specification with your mouse pointer. Kris's comment is from 08:49:00Z, your answer is from 08:48:19Z. So no need to make a solemn vow, you were 41 seconds faster for everybody to see.

Comment: @cartogram my bad, I misquoted. Your verb of choice was "abusing". Anyway, I think I'll just iron it out and move on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These refer to the popping of [champagne bottles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champagne), that, due to being carbonated, make an audible *pop* sound when opened - or louder, if shaken before opening. 
The use of champagne in these lyrics is linked to the popular conception of champagne as symbols of wealth and power. See what Wikipedia says:

> Royalty from throughout Europe spread the message of the unique sparkling wine from Champagne and its association with luxury and power in the 17th, 18th and 19th century. [...] Through advertising and packaging they sought to associate Champagne with high luxury, festivities, and rites of passage. **Their efforts coincided with the emergence of a middle class that was looking for ways to spend its money on symbols of upward mobility**

The key passage is the one I emphasised - it's not only that champagne was expensive and became a drink for the rich and powerful, but it became (through both luck, timing and careful branding) a product for the *nouveau riche*, middle-class people with access to money who want the trappings of nobility.

Answer (score 5):

It indicates they are opening champagne bottles, ie living an expensive, extravagant lifestyle because they are rich beyond the wildest dreams of normal men.

A lot of this type of music is effectively showing off - dancing/sleeping with attractive models, drinking the most expensive drinks in exclusive nightclubs etc. At the end of the day, they are just shouting, "Look how successful I am!"

Comment: Champagne bottles certainly pop, but do you have any independent source for the association with champagne?

Comment: Written citations, no, but the use in three of those songs (I have seen the videos) is directly connected with Crystal champagne, the de facto R&B artist's drink of choice - and also one of the most expensive. These songs are all about demonstrating wealth and success.

Comment: However, the phrase is also used elsewhere, by those who open other kinds of bottles, by those just referring to a session of 'drinking' or even just partying in general.

Comment: Not my downvote, by the way.

Comment: no worries - I'm never precious about votes. They are what people think.

Comment: @RoryAlsop splendid!

Comment: This is a good answer. I would add links to pertinent music videos.

Comment: @Tyler - will do after work. Can't get to them from here :-)

Answer (score 2):

It’s new to me, but it’s not surprise that [the Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=popping%20bottles%20) offers ‘to open an alcoholic beverage (to drink liquor)’.